# Change binary file in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, ipa

I made one app for iPhone and I upload my binary file in app store few days ago. Currently my app  status shows  **in review**,  now I want to change my `.ipa` file.

Can I change my `.ipa` file right now, when my app is **in review state**?

**or**

Do I have to wait for review completion and then re-upload my binary and wait for more days?

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can change your binary file when your app status is "in review state" and before it change to "Ready for sale". Before that you have to go to iTunes Connect and Discard your old binary.

For that, **In iTunes connect, go into 'Manage Your Applications' then click your application. Then 'View details' and press 'Binary Details' under 'Links'. You'll see the 'Reject this binary' in the upper right corner**. After you discard your binary you can go ahead and upload a new one.

After doing this you'll be again placed in a waiting queue from the start. It's like you are uploading a binary today and waiting for review.

For confirmation you can check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html)

> Rejecting Your Binary
>
> You can reject the binary you have submitted if its status is any of
>   the following: Missing Screenshot (iOS only), Waiting for Export
>   Compliance, Waiting For Review, In Review, Pending Developer Release,
>   or Pending Apple Release. Click the Reject Binary button on the Binary
>   Details page. This action removes your binary from the review queue.
>   You can then submit another update through Application Loader after
>   you move your app back to the Waiting For Upload state in iTunes
>   Connect. If you reject your binary, your app’s status changes to
>   Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your binary, the review process
>   starts over from the beginning.

Comment: How many days i have to wait, if i reject current binary and reupload my new binary as you suggested ?

Comment: @TheSimple : Review process starts over from the beginning. So minimum 7 days i guess.

Comment: it is not possible now to update my binary  file from this in review state ?

Comment: @TheSimple no. This is the only option you have. Or, whatever changes you have made those are not going to affect your app experience. Then what you can do is let this app get live and then you can go ahead and upload a new version.

Comment: my app is crashing in some condition will my app get rejected...?

Comment: depend on reviewer at apple, I they find crash binary'll get rejected, if not no problem.. But that's not the right way, I recomend u should change your binary.

Comment: @TheSimple as rptwsthi suggested it's better you go ahead and replace the binary. It's better to slow and steady ;)

Comment: @TheSimple -> don't reject your binary now , wait for live...then add other version... conclusion -> your app will be online(and you can submit new binary)

Comment: @Rajneesh071 even i was thinking of this. But what The Simple is saying is his app is crashing. It means user experience will be spoiled. And there are good chances of people rating app coz of this. Hence, as suggested by rptwsthi it's better if he rejects his binary now.

Comment: But make some logic ->(present app binary review time + new binary review time -> after this app will live**too much time **...)